# Android JAVA String Validation

Tags: android, string, validation

i have a question :

I want to create an app that take a String from user input. This String will be in an email format. So there's some requirement's :

1. .(full stop) can't be placed before @
2. .(full stop) and @ can't be more than one
3. .(full stop) and @ can't be side by side

Note : This is NOT a school homework(i just felt that this is like a homework after i typed it), i just want to learn more about String :D

I already did some research's but i still can't solve those problem's :D

Thanks all, and sory if i made  some mistake's, English is not my native languange :D

Comment: Why would you want to prevent 'dot' from appearing before @? it is valid.

Comment: Hm...yes i made a mistake, i think it's invalid :D
But it's okay, coz i think the first is the hardest one :D

Comment: Please help if you have some free time!
Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Universal Email Validation For Email

```
 if(eMailValidation(YourEmailString)){
          /// right  Email-id
      }
    public boolean eMailValidation(String emailstring) {
            Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
            Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(emailstring);
            return emailMatcher.matches();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Sir :D
If possible, i want to get the "manual" one..coz i want to know it's syntax and how to implement them :D
And i will have to change some requirement's so it's not just like a normal email

Thank you Sir :D

Comment: what you want actually ? i cant understand?

Comment: Sorry :D
Hm..maybe like using some loop's and if's and then using some method's like isDigit or isSpace in C :D

Comment: Hm..yes..i mean i want to check it in that way..
Like :
for (int i  = 0; i < strlen(example); i++){
if(isDigit(example[i]))return 0;
}
It's something like that, i called it manually :D
THanks Sir :D

Comment: well, i want to check those 3 requrement's...the isDigit is just for example :D
Do you understand what i mean?he2
Sorry Sir, English is not my native languange :D